# Wordpress table prefix must not be empty

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, innodb, mamp

I'm using the next: PhPStorm, MAMP PRO and Wordpress.

I create a new database to create a new Wordpress webpage, but when i fill all i get 'table prefix must not be empty'. Of course is not empty. I put wp_, it_, rt_, etc. But I get always the same error. I saw a post that maybe was due to MySQL version and I should create the tables InnoDB again. Of course it didn't work. I tried with an older version of MAMP PRO -actually the v.3-.

I try to do the same but I get the same error. I go to mysql directory and i cannot find any of these tables innodb_index_stats, innodb_table_stats, slave_master_info, slave_relay_log_info, slave_worker_info. I should create them, but I cannot do it with `'STATS_PERSISTENT=0;'`

¿What else can I do?

Comment: Are you creating this manually or through the WP install procedure?

Comment: That's with the interface of 5 minutes setup. I mean I don't configure wp-config.php. Even If I try that, the second step where you have to put the username, email, etc. I get the error: 'username invalid' or 'introduce a valid email'. And they are both right..

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily change your .htaccess to "RewriteEngine Off". The installation script requires the .php suffixes so your POST requests are getting lost.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine Off

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Getting edit suggestions to do the exact opposite of what I have answered. OP's error is caused by "RewriteEngine On" so it must be turned Off.

Edits which suggest turning "RewriteEngine On" are exactly backwards.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you updated MySQL (or MAMP) but failed to run `mysql_update`.

Comment: It could but I did it when I hadn't anything installed on my computer..